# How to set multiline textbox hint label in VB .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

This code works on textbox but not on multiline textbox how can I change this for my multiline textbox?

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
End Function
```

`SendMessage(Me.textbox1.Handle, &H1501, 0, "Enter User name here")`
this code come from this [How to set TextBox hint label in VB .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036028/how-to-set-textbox-hint-label-in-vb-net/19384773#19384773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. See

*You cannot set a cue banner on a multiline edit control or on a rich edit control.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner

Comment: thanks for the information I just changed my font-size property of the textbox to match the height I needed